# Append to beginning and ending of each line?

Tags: sed

I'm working on a `sed` script that creates a HTML file. I want to append paragraph tags to the beginning and ending of each line but can't figure out how that would work.

Right now I have the following `sed` script:

```
1i\
<html>\
<head><title>sed generated html</title></head>\
<body>\
<pre>
$a\
</pre>\
</body>\
</html>
```

How would I be able to enclose every line in a `<p>` and `</p>` tag?

Example:

**test.txt**

```
This is a test file.
This is another line in the test file.
```

Output with the `sed` script:

```
<html>
<head><title>sed generated html</title></head>
<body>
<pre>
<p>This is a test file.</p>
<p>This is another line in the test file.</p>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is <p> and </p> in your sample???

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3):

With **sed**:

Change your script to:

```
1i\
<html>\
<head><title>sed generated html</title></head>\
<body>\
<pre>
s/.*/<p>&<\/p>/
$a\
</pre>\
</body>\
</html>
```

Same as your command, but added `s/.*/<p>&<\/p>/`. Surround each line in file with `<p>` and `</p>`.
Use command `sed -f script File`

With **awk**:

**`cat script`**

```
BEGIN {
printf "<html>\n\
<head><title>sed generated html</title></head>\n\
<body>\n\
<pre>\n"
}
{print "<p>"$0"</p>"}
END {
printf "</pre>\n\
</body>\n\
</html>\n"
}
```

**`cat File`**

```
This is a test file.
This is another line in the test file.
```

**`Command:`**

```
awk -f script File
```

**`Sample:`**

```
AMD$ awk -f script File
<html>
<head><title>sed generated html</title></head>
<body>
<pre>
<p>This is a test file.</p>
<p>This is another line in the test file.</p>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about using `sed`?